# Use TEdit field to specify amount of generated files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

in XE5 I have made application where by default is loaded small **txt** file with multiple lines using OnShow function.
Also there is 1 **TEdit1** field with default value=**300** and TButton to save file in defined directory.

How would be possible to:
1.) using value in TEdit1 field to get that amount of files in that specified dir, value could be changed if needed;
2.) all generated files should be like: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt... etc.

Now buttons funcion is:

```
procedure TForm1.GenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName : String;
begin
  // Create a new directory
  dirName := 'gen';
  if DirectoryExists(dirName)
then
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('gen\default.txt')
else
  CreateDir(dirName);
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('gen\default.txt');
end;
```

Best regards,
G

---

the whole working code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IOUtils, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    SaveFile: TButton;
    Generate: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure LoadFile(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveFileClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure GenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.LoadFile(Sender: TObject);
begin
if FileExists('template.txt')then begin
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('template.txt');
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Cant find template.txt, add text and use SAVE button !!!');
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('template.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.GenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName, fName : String;
  i, max: integer;
begin
  // Create a new directory
  dirName := 'gen';

  if NOT DirectoryExists(dirName) then
    CreateDir(dirName);

  fName := Edit1.Text;
  max := StrToInt(fName);

  for i := 1 to max do begin
    fName := dirName + '\'+ IntToStr(i) + '.txt';
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile( fName );
  end;

end;
end.
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very idea to store data in visual components is somewhat smelly. But if you insist - then you can just store integer values in .TAG property. But okay, learn few casual functions below and learn `begin` and `end` keywords:

*Update: converting relative name to fully qualified for ForceDirectories. Used functions:*

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.ExpandUNCFileName
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.GetCurrentDir
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter

The code with using Delphi-provided ready-made function then becomes:

```
procedure TForm1.GenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName, fName : String;
  i, max: integer;
begin
  // Create a new directory
  dirName := 'gen';

  dirName := ExpandUNCFileName(dirName); 
  // converting possible relative path to absolute

  dirName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetCurrentDir) + dirName;
  // yet another way to do the same, as above
  // GCD function would return paths like "C:\" or like "C:\Users\Name\Documents"
  // so we don't know in advance if there would be slash at the end or not

  ForceDirectories(dirName);

  fName := EditField.Text;
  max := StrToInt(fName);

  // even better:  max := EditField.Tag; and change TAG property, not TEXT in IDE

  for i := 1 to max do begin
    fName := dirName + PathDelimiter + IntToStr(i) + '.txt';
    MemoField.Lines.SaveToFile( fName );
  end;

end;
```

One can also call `TDirectory.CreateDirectory(dirName);` instead of `ForceDirectories` but I cannot check now if the former works with relative paths or also requires path expansion before being called. If it can - then the non-changed `dirName` would be valid parameter to call the function directly.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory

---

You original function has a weird, broken structure actually. Double-save. I make below a proper structure of your original code for easy reading:

```
procedure TForm1.GenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dirName : String;
begin
  // Create a new directory
  dirName := 'gen';

  if DirectoryExists(dirName)
  then
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('gen\default.txt')
  else
    CreateDir(dirName);

  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('gen\default.txt');
end;
```

Comment: Why you are repeating OPself? `if not direxists then createdir;`

Comment: @Free - To make a point of how not properly indenting code can cause mistakes ('SaveToFile' is in fact outside the 'if').

Comment: So you know with ForceDirectories(dirName); you will just get error that cant create directory.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I believe OP knew about compound statements already, just had poor formatting. Original had harmless code duplication, while this example artificially made marginally harmful. I dont see a point.

Comment: @Free - No artificial intervention, it's the exact same code as in the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, oh, I see now.

Comment: @goaul well, yes, there is a restrictions on FD in Delphi - just described in newer Delphi help. Fixed Also please check this function - it may or may not work with related path as well: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you, both ways work like intended. :)